# Allowing access to particular reports in a report folder

Tags: reports-api, custom-reports

I have several reports created & saved in a specific folder. Now I want to provide access to certain reports & not all reports to a user. Whats the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Even ["Advanced Report & dashboard sharing"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=analytics_sharing_enable.htm) is done per folder, not per report.

Enable this option if you haven't done so already, reorganize your reports so the ones you want to hide are in another folder, then share just that folder to your selected users (probably best is to share it with public group or role... Sharing to single users is pain and you don't want to do it every time there's a new joiner).

The only other way to hide stuff is when the report relies on object from managed package for example and this user doesn't have license assigned. He'll be able to see the reports name but not drill down to it; see the old dashboard snapshot but fail to refresh it.